# Cisco ip phone serivices Authentication URL response

Tags: c++, qt, cisco

Я пишу программу на Qt для работы с cisco ip phone services. Использую QNetworkAccessManager чтобы делать post XML объектом на телефон и QTcpServer с сокетом и  QTextStream чтобы отвечать на запросы авторизации телефонов (просто пишу http-заголовки и "AUTHORIZED" в text stream).

```
QString cTime = currTime.currentDateTimeUtc().toString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");

QTextStream os(socket); os << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
      "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
      "Date: " + cTime + " GMT\r\n"
      "Connection: close\r\n"
      "\r\n"
      "AUTHORIZED";
```

Проблема в том, что телефон не принимает ответ и отвечает `<CiscoIPPhoneError Number="4" />`
До этого я то же самое делал на node.js, просто писал AUTHORIZED в объект http.ServerResponse. Не могу понять, в чём проблема сделать такое же Qt

Comment: Разобрался.
На CallManagere вместе с полем "Authentication url" было заполенено поле "Secure Authentication URL". И то, что я принимал за GET, оказалось "Client hello"...
Очистил "Secure Authentication URL" и теперь авторизация работает